# Unable to save RDD's and DF's in a Spark Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

When running in a single node no-cluster mode, whenever I do `rdd.saveAsTextFile("file://...")` or `df.write().csv("file://...")` it creates a folder at that path with `part-files` and a file called `_SUCCESS`.

But when I use the same code for cluster mode, it doesn't work. I doesn't throw any errors but there are no `part-files` created in that folder. Though the folder and the `_SUCCESS` file are created, the actual part files data is not.

I am not sure what exactly the problem is here. Any suggestions on how to solve this are greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since in cluster mode, tasks are performed in `worker machines`

You should try to save the file in `hadoop` or `S3` or some `fileserver`, like `ftp` if you are running in cluster mode.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a way by which the spark workers send the data to the master and store there instead?